# Unable passing values to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<!--SERVER Query and Return function-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getreport()
    {
        $("button").click(function()
        {
            var id = $("#idF").val();  //assigning form values
            var report= $("#reportF").val();
            var date = $("#dateF").val();

            $.post("report.php", {idP:id,reportP:report,dateP:date}, function(data){
                $("#results").html(data); //updating the page with results
                }); //trying to pass the 3 fields to report.php
        });
    }
    </script>

<form id="queryReports">
        ID: <input type="text" style='text-transform:uppercase' id="idF">   Report:<input type="text" style='text-transform:uppercase' id="reportF">
        Date(dd/mm/YYYY): <input type="date" id="dateF" id="Study_dateF">           
        <button  id="button" onclick="getreport()">SEARCH</button>

</form>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction why this code seems to do nothing? When I click the button I expect the report.php to be called with the values I pass to it from the form. However i get nothing from it, I checked the php log and there is nothing that is being passed if I call report.php using the button.

On the other hand if I run report.php with hardcoded values I get the result. I suspect there is something I'm missing in my jQuery/Javascript

Comment: If you open the developer tools (Chrome F12), navigate to the network and hit at your page the button, what do you see? Does this fires an AJAX request? What is the response status?

Comment: `<input type="date" id="dateF" id="Study_dateF">` you have 2 id's here and is most likely why your code is failing.

Comment: Try it w/o the two ID's, as @Fred-ii- pointed out.

Comment: Also, #results is completely empty when you click the button?

Comment: @Christos thats the problem I dont see the ajax nor any calls to report.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the catch , I made the correction but still no luck its like my report.php is invisible

Comment: @LeoWilson yes because it doesnt seem like my POST is being passed on to report.php its really weird or so simple I cant see it

Comment: how are you using this as btw, `http://localhost` or `file:///`? php needs to run off a webserver. If localhost then use error reporting and the console should have thrown you something about the two id's

Comment: @user7421969 I noticed the edit here http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41663419/2 and someone http://stackoverflow.com/a/41663597/1415724 based themselves on your original post and you did not mark your edit as an additional edit. That isn't how things are done here on Stack. I have rolled your question back to its original post. If you made a mistake, you need to mark it under your original post, not overwrite it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks will remember for next time

Comment: @user7421969 You're welcome. An added reason as to why you should always post what you tried under the original post and what changed is that some (answers) stand to get downvoted and they won't be happy campers about it ;-) You can re-edit your question if you want, but please post the "new" code you're now using under the original and marked as something to the effect of: *"I made a mistake/here is the code I am using.... it is still not working..."* type of thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- im running it through local host , and nope nothing on console. trust me i have checked everything I know before posting

Comment: @user7421969 btw, how are you getting results back from `$("#results").html(data);`? I don't see an id (element) bearing that id. Probably another reason why it's not "showing" results and that it is trying to send you something back.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No I'm not getting anything. I omitted that div on purpose in my code so as not to clutter it with stuff I know would work if the rest of the code functionned. I do have it defined in my webpage. The problem with this whole code is that it is not passing the info to the php so the php has nothing to look for and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is flawed because you are mixing inline event listener with a jQuery one.

The code inside the jQuery one won't fire until the next time you click the button

Get rid of the inline one and also change button type to `"button"` or it will default to `"submit"` and will submit the form through default process

```
<button  id="button" type="button">SEARCH</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {      
  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#idF").val(); //assigning form values
    var report = $("#reportF").val();
    var date = $("#dateF").val();

    $.post("report.php", {
      idP: id,
      reportP: report,
      dateP: date
    }, function(data) {
      $("#results").html(data); //updating the page with results
    }); //trying to pass the 3 fields to report.php
  });
});
```

You can simplify this by adding `name` attributes to input elements and using [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form

Example input:

```
<input type="text"  name="idP" id="idF">
```

JS

```
$(function() {  
  // use submit event instead of click on button    
  $("#queryReports").submit(function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
    $.post("report.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      $("#results").html(data); //updating the page with results
    }); //trying to pass the 3 fields to report.php
  });
});
```

Comment: and what about `<input type="date" id="dateF" id="Study_dateF">`?

Comment: I posted [that comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663419/unable-passing-values-to-php/41663613?noredirect=1#comment70525141_41663419) about it under their question earlier where you removed one you posted. I would have thought that you'd of seen it; maybe you didn't (?). Edit: I just don't want somebody to downvote you. If there is one, I can assure you that it would not have come from me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- have simplified it where ID's are irrelevant and can serialize whole form

Comment: Ok. Well, the OP will need to respond to answers given, including yours of course ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- the ID is an issue, but not the main one. The compounded listeners was the big one

Comment: thank you @charlietfl I will apply your fixes and see whats going on. Ill reboot my server also just in case.

Comment: @charlietfl [This comment I left them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663419/unable-passing-values-to-php#comment70526028_41663419) might be worth noting; I just noticed that now.

Comment: @charlietfl IT WORKS!!!!! thank you so much ! Now I can focus on fine tuning my php. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$("button").click()` function.
You are calling the `getreport()` function through `onclick="getreport()"` on your button, but when it calls the function, it can't reach the AJAX request because it's inside of the `$("button").click()` function.

Comment: and what about `<input type="date" id="dateF" id="Study_dateF">`?

Comment: Hello thanks for answering but yea I tried it too before posting the question and same result

Comment: The second id will not be rendered by the browser, so it won't show up when you inspect the element (Chrome F12). It does not break the code though, I just tried it with a simple setup and it didn't break. But because it's not rendered, it's better when it's removed or turned into a `class`.

Comment: @user7421969 You wrote `preventDefault()` wrong... Maybe that's the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I found some errors in the code.  You should use double quotes for attributes, never give an element two ID's, and prevent default when handling click events on submit buttons.  You should also avoid using two handlers to do the same thing, when one is created inside the other.  Try this:

```js
$("button").click(function(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDeafult();
            var id = $("#idF").val();  //assigning form values
            var report= $("#reportF").val();
            var date = $("#dateF").val();

            $.post("report.php", {idP:id,reportP:report,dateP:date}, function(data){
                $("#results").html(data); //updating the page with results
                }); //trying to pass the 3 fields to report.php
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="queryReports">
        ID: <input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" id="idF">   Report:<input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" id="reportF">
        Date(dd/mm/YYYY): <input type="date" id="dateF">           
        <button  id="button">SEARCH</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Yours is the only answer (so far) that addressed the `<input type="date" id="dateF" id="Study_dateF">` issue.

Comment: thank you for the answer. yes my mistake about double IDs, been working on this whole night copy paste is a mean one